# Program automatically to insert signature

Tags: docusignapi

I have a document that requires multiple signatures.   Instead of the last signature being down by a person, can I automatically insert a signature?  I am using the SOAP API.   I did see this question asked, but have seen mixed answers over the last 7 years.

Answer (score 0):

No, the DocuSign eSignature SOAP API does not support robo-signing.

Comment: Great thanks for confirming.   Do any of the API's support robo-signing?  Or is this just not encouraged or supported anywhere.  I am looking for recent direction on this from Docusign before I get too involved.   Thanks so much

Comment: The DocuSign Signature Appliance does: https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/DocuSign-Signature-Appliance-Formerly-known-as-CoSign-Product-Version